# App not showing in google play app but does through web browser

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Is anyone having issues viewing their apps through an Android device on Google Play? WE average 20 - 30 sales a day, and two days ago sales just disappeared. (1 -2 a day). When searching for the app it shows through a web browser but not on any device that we have.

We unpublished, republished, checked all settings so on.

We uploaded a new app 2 days ago, and that is the only app we can see through the google play app on a device. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Maybe is that device not compatible. You may add your manifest (without the activity part).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have inadvertantly set a distribution setting to not allow certain devices of OS versions.  This would result in the app showing on the web (which doesn't always filter based on the devices you have registered).

If your app isn't supported on certain devices, it will not show up in searches on the device itself.

Bottom line, double check your settings - I am not having any issues with my app showing up in the web or on my device (and I am seeing my normal expected download rates).

Comment: Thank you both for your input, I'll do some investigating on the "Settings" issue, however, we have several different android devices and none of them are showing the app in a search on the google play app. Even the devices that already have the app downloaded and viewable on them don't show it in a search. Some of our apps have been recently updated and some have been in the store as is for months, so.. not sure why all of the sudden none (but the most recently published one) is showing in google play app.

Comment: You may have your OS set to 4.2 or something like that - which would eliminate all of your current devices (unless you are rocking a Nexus with the latest OS).  Also, check your country settings - start big.